# How to map string to number in java?

Tags: java, string, mapping, numbers

Given a text string like "apple", I want to obtain a number. So every time I do that with apple I get the same number. How can this be done in java?

Thank you.

**EDIT:** well, I think I didn't explain myself well. I mean an existing Java function that implements a map like this. An example of a function like this would be:
 a->1, b->2, c->3,...

```
apple -> 11616125
```

Comment: would you also like fries with that? it'll be 12.75$ thank you.

Comment: Mechanical snail: Yeah, something like that

Comment: If `apple -> 11616125`, then wouldn't you also have `aafafabe -> 11616125`? Seems like a bad strategy...

Comment: @beerbajay: you're right, it isn't an injective mapping although aafafabe is not in the set of meaningful words... Anyway, it was just an example for explaining that I wanted a functional approach and not by data structures...

Comment: Was there something wrong with `hashCode`?

Comment: @beerbajay: no, that was the answer, thanks. The only thing was that I didn't know that a hashCode method was implemented for strings, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer would be to use the hashCode method of String.

Answer (score 4):

This is what maps are for.

```
Map<String, Integer> lookup = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
lookup.put("apple", 1);
lookup.get("apple"); // returns 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<String, Ingereg> map = new HashMap<String, Ingereg>();
map.put("apple", 10);
map.get("apple");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the string to map to a specific number, then create a `Map<String, Integer>` populate it with your mappings, and then use it whenever you need to map a string.  For example:

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("Apple", 0);  // A nice round apple
    map.put("Banana", 7); // A nice bent banana
    ...
    System.out.println("The apple is " + map.get("apple"));
```

If you simply want to a string to map to the same number each time ... without specifying the number ... then call `hashcode()` on the string object.  That is guaranteed to return the same number on any given HotSpot Java platform, because the algorithm used is specified and determinate.